# Managing DocuSign brand logos via API

Tags: c#, rest, docusignapi

We are using the DocuSign API with the `docusign-csharp-client` and REST API with no issues.

We now want to automate our Brand creation, so we are building code to map to the `AccountsApi`. However, I cannot find out how to get or set the logo images used for a brand: the API documentation is sketchy at best.

For example, the API method [updateLogo](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Accounts/AccountBrands/updateLogo/) is implemented in two forms: `UpdateBrandLogoByType` and `UpdateBrandLogoByTypeWithHttpInfo` - neither method has any place to put the logo image data.

I looked at the `GetBrandLogoByType` method but this returns `void` !?

Finally I tried `GetBrand` on an existing brand with logos already defined, this returns the data the logo fields set to some sort of resource URL: 

`"email":"/brands/[brandID]/logos/email",
"primary":"/brands/[brandID]/logos/primary"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure of C sharp SDK, as its an open source and since these are least used method so might be implementation is not done correctly. As its an open source you can create your branch and update the code to work it correctly. I tested these Brand APIs using Postman and it is working correctly, you can update or get the logo correctly. In get call it returns a JPEG image correctly in the response and I can see the image in Postman.

Comment: I looks like their Swagger API codegen is at fault.. I will try using the REST calls directly myself and see what the issue is.. many thanks for the pointer